# Ethernet (driver) failure. Windows blames BIOS but device works fine in Linux

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, drivers, bios, firmware

I have a problem with an HP 655 Notebook that originally came with Windows 7 preinstalled, I made a backup to a local FTP server using a linux live USB, formatted it, and then installed Windows 8 (8.1). Since the ethernet NIC didn't have a valid driver, I downloaded and installed the driver provided on the [official HP download site for this model](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5225021&lang=es&cc=mx), every other hardware worked fine with the drivers except for the ethernet NIC. The windows device manager says that the driver is correctly installed, but that the firmware does not provide "enough information" to communicate to the device properly. It also says that a BIOS update may solve the issue.

I don't think it's a hardware failure nor a BIOS or firmware problem, since I managed to copy the whole 130 GB of data back and forth from the server to the PC on linux via ethernet. I also don't have a way to confirm wether it worked before with Windows 7 or not. Why is Windows unable to properly use or initialize the device? Is there a workaround for this? Also, I don't have a screencap because I have had already returned the machine. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, there is one update available, but I don't know wether its chip was already up to date or not.

Comment: Can you explain to me why you would ignore the update if windows tells you that the driver needs an upgrade? Sorry, please update your answer once you update the driver.

Comment: I don't think you read it correctly. The hardware worked fine on Windows 7 and goes full speed on Linux, I am asking *why* it wouldn't work on Windows 8 and why would Windows blame the BIOS or the firmware?.

Comment: I read that part clearly. I'm no BIOS nerd, and I see that this is senseless- but why not give it a try?

Comment: @RookieTEC9 updating the BIOS isn't always as easy or smooth as you'd like - most manufacturer's documents I've read say to **NOT** upgrade the BIOS unless there's a specific need to - *if it ain't broke don't fix it, or it might get broke*

Comment: :O Okay, sorry 'bout that. Told you I'm no BIOS nerd.

Comment: I can add: what if with the new BIOS it will not work with the other systems? It is rare but it can happen too.

Comment: Are you saying that Windows 8 is somehow not compatible with the current BIOS? because I also suspect that.